# How to get from a file exactly what I want in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash

How to get from a file exactly what I want in Linux?
I have: `123456789012,refid2141,test1,test2,test3` and I want this:  
 `123456789012 or 123456789012 test3`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please clarify your question. Do you want to use Python to extract the correct fields from a text file, under a Linux environment? What have you tried so far? Please check the help section on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: i want to use bash to extract the corect fields from a text file, I try with this cut -c1-13 but take all the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ echo  "123456789012,refid2141,test1,test2,test3" | awk -F "," '{print $1}'
123456789012

$ echo  "123456789012,refid2141,test1,test2,test3" | awk -F "," '{printf("%s, %s", $1,$5)}'
123456789012, test3
```

Answer (score 0):

foo.csv:

```
123456789012,refid2141,test1,test2,test3
```

```py
import csv
with open("foo.csv", "rt") as fd:
    data = list(csv.reader(fd))
print(data[0][0])
```

For a bash solution:

```bash
cat foo.csv | cut -d',' -f1
```